# Keras Input Shape Issue

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I can find many questions and answers related to my question but somehow they did not solve my problem. I have data with shape (10584, 56) and specified input_shape=(10584,56) in the code but getting following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10584, 56).
```

I have somehow idea that I have to reshape my input data frame but not sure how. Following is my code:

```
y = df['Target']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.2)
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64,input_shape(10584,56),activation='relu'))
```

Any help/suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always an additional dimension for the batch size that you need add even if you want to use a batch size of 1.

Another possibility: If in fact your samples are not 2d vectors but 1d vectors of size 64 and 10584 is the number of samples you have, than the number of samples is not part of the input shape. You only provide the size of a single sample. Keras will take care of splitting your data into batches and setting the network up the right way.